# Google Sheets: Count Uniques, give them ID's and push ID's in a new column

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

In Column A i have dates. In a first step i want to count the Unique Dates in Column A, which i could do with the =COUNTUNIQUE function.

Example:

Column A:

13.11.2018
13.11.2018
13.11.2018
10.11.2018
10.11.2018
10.11.2018
10.11.2018
09.11.2018
13.11.2018

So i have 3 different UNIQUES in this example (real list is much longer), in a next step i want to give each UNIQUE an ID from 1 (first UNIQUE in list) to X (last Unique value in the list, in this example it would be 3). Finally my goal is to get the Unique Values in Column B:

(A)13.11.2018 (B)1
(A)13.11.2018 (B)1
(A)13.11.2018 (B)1
(A)10.11.2018 (B)2
(A)10.11.2018 (B)2
(A)10.11.2018 (B)2
(A)10.11.2018 (B)2
(A)10.11.2018 (B)2
(A)09.11.2018 (B)3
(A)13.11.2018 (B)1

Can somebody help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=ArrayFormula(if(A:A="","","(A)"&A:A&"(B)"&match(A:A,unique(A:A),0)))
```

[image]